# SQL table to Array to check in VB Forms

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

Let's say I have a table `People` (ID, DateBirth, Sex, Salary) and I do

```
SELECT ID 
FROM PEOPLE
```

Now I will get a result set with 1 column and N rows. How can I convert this table ([see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCL3m.png)) to an array, like

```
array = [ 101, 19, 33, 50, 6, 9 ]
```

After this I want to obtain that array in a Forms developed in Visual Basic to check with and `If` condition like this:

```
If i in array Then
    Update ....
End If
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You've tagged with VBA, but Winforms is .NET, so are you using VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure “why” you need the array; however, the following code should give you what you want… assuming the `id` field is an `Integer` type in the `People` `DataTable`

```
Dim arrayData = (From dataRow In People.AsEnumerable() Select dataRow.Field(Of Integer)("id")).ToArray()
```

In my small tests, this worked as expected.